# Python Selenium with BeautifulSoup: PHP redirect removes useful information from the URL. How to fix?

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I am trying to use Python Selenium with BeautifulSoup to scrape data off a PHP-enabled website.

But the site does an immediate redirect:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta content="0;url=index.php" http-equiv="refresh"/>
</head>
<body>
<p>Redirecting to <a href="index.php">TestRail</a> ..</p>
</body>
</html>
```

... when I just give the URL "https://mysite.thing.com"

When I change it to: "https://mysite.thing.com/index.php" ... I get a 404 error.

How to get around this? Any suggestions appreciated!

Comment: Can you provide the code, no one can help you without the code

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because php requested webpages are generated on the fly with a randomly generated token, thereby going directly to the index.php will take you know here because your 'token' is nil, I would go through the motions in selenium to navigate the page as if you were doing it instead of trying to skip ahead.

I could be totally wrong about the php thing BTW, it's a vague memory....

Answer (score 0):

It worked to use this simpler code:

```py
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

import ssl

ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context




urlpage = "https://my.site.com"

print(urlpage)

driver.get(urlpage)
html = driver.page_source
print(html)
```

This follows the redirect and does what I expect.